# Gridx and Gridy not changing anything

Tags: java, user-interface, constraints

I am having an error where my gridx and gridy from GridBoxConstraints do nothing. I have multiple objects I'm trying to add and change the positions of, but none of them are changing and are simply staying where I left them in the first place, as if I never used the grix and gridy.

```
public class Applet extends JApplet{
private JButton b1;
private JButton b2;
private JFrame f;
private JPanel p;
private JRadioButton r;
 private JRadioButton r1;
 //private JTextField demoField;
 GridBagConstraints c =new GridBagConstraints();


public Applet()
{
    gui();
}
public void gui()
{
    f=new JFrame("Applet!");
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(500,500);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    p = new JPanel();
    p.setVisible(true);

    //demoField = new JTextField();



    r =  new JRadioButton("Leave a message!!");
    r1 =  new JRadioButton("Draw a shape!!");

    b1 = new JButton("Button!");
    b1.setVisible(true);
    b2 = new JButton("Button 2!");
    b2.setVisible(true);
    r1.setVisible(true);
    r.setVisible(true);
    //setting grid numbers
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy = 0;
   //adding to frame
    p.add(b2,c);
    //setting grid numbers
    c.gridx = 5;
    c.gridy = 2;
    p.add(r1,c);
    //setting grid numbers
    c.gridx = 5;
    c.gridy = 5;

    p.add(r,c);
    //setting grid numbers
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
   p.add(b1,c);

    //p.add(demoField);
    f.add(p);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `gridx` and `gridy` to be used meaningfully, you need to also use `gridwidth` and `gridheight`.  In a `GridBagLayout`,  the cells (and consequently rows and columns) of the grid do not have a fixed size, but query their contents' preferred sizes, and then give them extra space as determined by their weights (yet another constraint parameter - as always see the [fine documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) for details).

Also, while it is OK to reuse a GridBagConstraints on multiple objects, it is confusing to modify it before reuse without resetting all of the fields (some are defaulted to zero).   Easiest is to create another constraints object for the next child component, if they differ.

So:

```
b1 = new JButton("Button!");
b1.setVisible(true);
b2 = new JButton("Button 2!");
b2.setVisible(true);
r1.setVisible(true);
r.setVisible(true);
//setting grid numbers
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
c.gridwidth = 5;
c.gridheight = 2;

//adding to frame
p.add(b2,c);
c = new GridBagConstraints();
//setting grid numbers
c.gridx = 5;
c.gridy = 2;
p.add(r1,c);
....
```

and so on.

The layout of `GridBagLayout` is very complex, and judging from your example you may want something entirely different:  if you are expecting a fixed-size grid, and want there to be empty spaces in the grid that "skip" rows and columns, use `GridLayout`, not GridBagLayout.